# MySQL Query with count and group by

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I've got table a table with different records for publishers, each record have a date in a column of type timestamp.

```
id | id_publisher | date
1           1      11/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
2           1      12/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
3           2      01/2013 03:09:40 p.m.
4           3      01/2013 03:09:40 p.m.
5           4      11/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
6           4      02/2013 03:09:40 p.m.
7           4      02/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
```

I need a count for number of records published by each  publisher for each month. For example

```
Month    |  id_publisher         | num
11/2012  |          1            |   1
11/2012  |          2            |   0
11/2012  |          3            |   0
11/2012  |          4            |   1
.....
02/2013  |          4            |   2
```

I tried with 
`select count(id) from raw_occurrence_record group by month(date), id_publisher;`

but, it did not work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assuming that your date is an actual `datetime` column:

```
SELECT MONTH(date), YEAR(date), id_publisher, COUNT(*)
FROM raw_occurrence_record
GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date), id_publisher
```

You can concatenate your month & year like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(date), '/', YEAR(date)) AS Month, id_publisher, COUNT(*)
FROM raw_occurrence_record
GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date), id_publisher
```

To find months where there are no records, you will need a date table. If you can't create one, you can `UNION ALL` a calendar table like so:

```
SELECT a.year, a.month, b.id_publisher, COUNT(b.id_publisher) AS num
FROM
  (SELECT 11 AS month, 2012 AS year
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 12, 2012
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, 2013
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 2013) a
LEFT JOIN raw_occurence_record b
  ON YEAR(b.date) = a.year AND MONTH(b.date) = a.month
GROUP BY a.year, a.month, b.id_publisher
```

### [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71d2d/1)