# How do I get domain name and number of emails in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table looks like following

```
Email                Domain
------               ------
test@gmail.com       gmail.com
test@gmail.com       gmail.com
test@gmail.com       gmail.com
test@yahoo.com       yahoo.com
test@yahoo.com       yahoo.com
test@outlook.com     outlook.com
```

How do I write a sql query to get the following result

```
Expected result
---------------
gmail.com    3
yahoo.com    2
outlook.com  1
```

Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `select domain,count(*) as result from table group by domain`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query with count and group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344810/mysql-query-with-count-and-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest use of [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
   SELECT domain, COUNT(*)
     FROM mytable
 GROUP BY domain
```

Comment: @user3458584 If you find any answer helpful then up vote that or Accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by and Count(*) function, Try this

```
select Domain,count(*) from Table_Name group by Domain
```